# Assets 2 There was an error uploading your file: Your upload directory isn’t writable

Tags: assets

After deploying my site to a production server I am encountering errors when uploading files in Assets. Uploads in the native File Manager work fine.

Running EE 2.5.5 and Assets 2.0.5 on Windows 2008 IIS.

Error Message: There was an error uploading your file: Your upload directory isn’t writable.

I've checked permissions for the expressionengine/cache folder and they are ok. Thumbnails and such get generated in the assets cache folder.

I was also running into a duplicate folder listing which was resolved by following this thread: https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/not_indexing_correctly?utm_content=topic_link&utm_medium=email&utm_source=reply_notification

I have tried with and without the following config overrides without success:

```
/*-- Assets --*/
//$env_config['assets_site_url'] = '/index.php';
//$env_config['assets_cp_path'] = './';
```

I'm not sure what else to try here... help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuno,

Can you make sure that /system/expressionengine/cache/ and its Assets subfolders are set to the equivalent of 777 permissions? You'll also need to check that for your individual file upload preference locations on your server.

You may also want to make sure your temporary folder is writable.  A sys admin could help you with that.

-Lisa

Comment: Both the cache and upload folders are writable. I can upload files via native file manager and assets generates thumbnails in the cache folder for existing files. I'm not sure what else to try :\

Comment: Is this a site that I can login and look at? If so, could you send FTP and Superadmin details via support@pixelandtonic.com? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help with this -- for anyone else having this issue, make sure you add "Everyone" with full read/write permissions to your upload directory.